# Wrong pointers while trying to allocate pages in kernel virtual address space

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, page-caching

I am working on a Linux driver on x86-64 CentOS 7. 
We have a kernel module  which reads and writes into files .
This module tries to get pages which are guaranteed to be contiguous.
It works fine when I try smaller `read/write` jobs of 5 GB or 10 GB. I get correct kernel virtual address space pointers like `0xffff 8xxx xxxx xxxx`
However if I try a bigger job /data (say 20 to 50 GB) then I get these address pointers which look like `0x0000 00xx xxxx xxxxx` . These are not kernel virtual address space pointers.

Due to this I see a OS crash .
However, if I clear cache frequency during the job by using `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`  then it works fine and I get correct kernel virtual address space pointers.

My apologies for this vague type of question. 
Any hints and suggestion are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your allocation failed. Is there a return status to check?

Comment: There is a return status check and allocation does not fail. It allocates at wrong location , once the cache is full.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. It's not surprising that the kernel folks did not expect allocations of that size in the system space.

Comment: It works fine on CentOS 6.x . But it does not work when I migrate that to CentOS 7.x . Looks like something has changed in page caching and re-claim logic in 7.x onwards.